# How to persist user-specific premium status in a Next.js web app with Redux, Firebase, and Stripe, so users retain it after logging in?

Tags: javascript, next.js, redux, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for users to purchase premium subscriptions, however I store their premium status in a Redux Persist State, and after they log out, the state refreshes and when they log back in, they have to purchase a premium subscription again.

I tried installing Redux Persist so I can save it in local storage, however that only partially fixed the problem, once the user logs out, the premium status is reset.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getAuth, onIdTokenChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setPremiumStatus } from "@/redux/userSlice";

export default function usePremiumStatus(user) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const premiumStatus = useSelector((state) => state.user.premium);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      return onIdTokenChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        if (user) {
          const tokenResult = await user.getIdTokenResult();
          dispatch(
            setPremiumStatus(tokenResult.claims.stripeRole === "premium")
          );
        } else {
          dispatch(setPremiumStatus(false));
        }
      });
    },
    [user],
    dispatch
  );

  return premiumStatus;
}
```

Above is how I set my premium status, initially it is set to "false", but the dispatch function makes it true. Is there any way to link it to the user specifically, and how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unsafe approach as the customer can easily modify their localStorage, so it looks like that they have the premium status.

The best way forward is to send a request to Stripe every time to find a Customer with the provided email, and check if they have an active Subscription.

I don't know exactly how you're integrated with Stripe, so I can't give a more specific advice, but I hope you can adapt the above high-level logic to your case.